# How much memory i actual get on azure-web-sites in standard mode

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Whenever, for example, i create a S2-tier **standard** website hosting plan i got 2 cores, 3.5 GB ram and 50 GB storage "Quotas".

What is the correct interpretation of "Quotas" in this case? I do have all of 3.5 GB for my website applications? Or the 3.5 GB are shared with the Operation System?

Thankful for any reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VM you get for your site has 2 cores and 3.5 GB of RAM. That is going to be shared between your site and the OS.

Basically the different tiers in the Standard Sku refer to different VM instances offerings. S2 being a VM with 3.5GB and 2 cores that runs an OS that has your site in it.

That is of course different from the storage quota where you just get 50 GB for your sites that are in that tier.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/websites/

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. 
Any idea of the current consumption of RAM that the O.S have on Standard machines? 

Many Thanks.

Comment: @MárioBraga - there's really no exact # here. It's a Windows Server VM running IIS, so you can do your own guesstimates based on advertised specs of each tier. Or... check it programmatically (maybe with the \Memory\Available MBytes perf counter, or language-level SDK call...).